# Testing combination of methods when every component method is already tested

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Consider the example below:

```
void Whole()
{
   A().B().C();
}
```

I've already written test methods for `A`, `B`, `C`. These are used in many different possible ways, for example `A().C().B()` or `B().A().C()` or `B().C().A()`. One of them is used in `Whole` method. There are 3! combination when all of them corporate in.

**Question:** is there any necessity to write test for any used combination such as what `Whole` uses?

**Update:** Basically, `A` and `B` and `C` are `query objects` and chaining them simply `and`-ens them. But other idea on what these method could be are very welcomed.

**Update 2:**
Consider `h(x)` = `f(x)` **+** `g(x)`. If I test f(x), g(x), and test **+** operator for working fine, do I still need to test `h(x)` assuming the same test context exists for all of the `f`, `g`, and `h` function ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What would happen if someone came along a changed the implementation of `Whole` to this:

```
void Whole()
{
   A().C().B();
}
```

if you didn't have a test you wouldn't know, and the presumably bad stuff would happen in your application.

So you need to test `Whole` for sure. But what type of test do you need? If whole is part of the same class as `A()` `B()` and `C()` and these methods modify the state of that class in some observable way then you could just have a state based test which validates that the expected state changes happen when `Whole` is called. As `Whole` is void and you don't elaborate on other potential methods I can't determine if this type of test is appropriate.

If `A()` `B()` and `C()` call other classes to do their work or are function in other classes then you would need an interaction based test and you would use mocks or test doubles to check that the expected interactions happen when you call `Whole` ie verify that `A()` is called first, then `B()` and finally `C()`.

See the difference between state and interaction based tests [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/testing-on-toilet-testing-state-vs.html)

I don't doubt that your functions will perform correctly together, but you need to test that they are being called correctly. this might be better as an interaction test rather than a state test (which the testing of the individual queries would be - even though the state is in the DB). You might benefit from making the test for `Whole` just verify that `A()` is called first, then `B()` and finally `C()` and either ignore the results from the DB or provide mock implementations of `A()` `B()` and `C()` for those tests.

Alternatively ditch the `Whole` method completely and let you client call `A().B().C()` themselves, then you shift the responsibility for checking they are doing the right thing to them. But IMHO if you provide the `Whole` method you should test that it does what you expect, even if that means 15 tests (its not really that many)

Comment: is there some property of your class you can query which you can tell the difference between `A().B().C()` and `A().C().B()` after you have called `Whole`?

Comment: Then how have you tested `A() B() and C()` individually?

Comment: I said they are query objects. I executed each one and check if they return the expected rows from db per say.

Comment: So can't you check that when you call `Whole` then execute the composite query that the expected results are returned from the DB?

Comment: Yes but as said before, A,B,C do filtering. There are many things like 'Whole'. You may can see, there are 15 possible combinations can be formed using A,B and C. Testing all of these 15 is tedious. Also, I think when A,B, and C do their job well, they also works fine together, but I doubt and this is why I ask here.

Comment: As I understand, in first options you are suggesting a cross-cutting test in which DB is get hit. In the second option, nothing is tested and as you said the responsibility is shifted. Did I get fine?

Comment: 3 options. 1. Test correct result with database. 2. Test correct interactions with mock queries. 3. Remove whole method and leave testing of combinations to the client. This option is no good if your code is the client :)

Comment: Brilliant. I think I will go for option #2. Thanks a lot.